# UnicodeDecodeError trying to open a json file

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, error-handling

When I run this:

```
import json, sys  

with open('/Users/mac/Desktop/export-2017-04-28-0235-25014395ac.json', 'r') as json_data:
    d = json.load(json_data)
print(d)
```

It returns an error that I'm not exactly sure what to think of. I've done my research and I'm not sure I understand what's wrong. If someone can help me out that would be great.

Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mac/Desktop/untitled.py", line 4, in <module>
    d = json.load(json_data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 296, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 39966: ordinal not in range(128)
[Finished in 0.5s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python3 -OO -u "/Users/mac/Desktop/untitled.py"]
[dir: /Users/mac/Desktop]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

Answer (score 4):

JSON expects you to do the decoding. 99% of the time `utf-8` does the job.

```
import json, sys  

with open('/Users/mac/Desktop/export-2017-04-28-0235-25014395ac.json', 
        'r', encoding='utf-8') as json_data:
    d = json.load(json_data)
print(d)
```

Comment: @puffballjack: For t other 2% of the time try `encoding='latin-1'`.

Comment: Thanks, is there any way you could help me with the next question I have I couldn't find a specific solution to that either. I know there is a lot of questions similar but I couldn't make any of the solutions work and couldn't figure out myself so.